# How do I refresh a page in single html5 jquery mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing an app using jquery mobile 1.4. I have this problem that when I edit an item using an edit form, the changes is saved in the localStorage but when I visit the list view page it does not reflect unless I manually refresh the page.

My save event of the form is like this

```
                   //After the selected employees has been edited
localStorage.setItem("employees", JSON.stringify(employees));   //set the update values to localstorage
alert('Employee Updated Successfully');
    $('#employees_list').listview('refresh');

 $.mobile.changePage("#home_page");
```

So I don't refresh it manually I added

```
                            history.go(0);
```

The problem with history.go(0); is that after compiling with phonegap it shows a blank screen and takes quit a while when it reloads which makes it seem as if the app has crashed.

So any suggestion on how to refresh the listview page without having to reload the entire html file?
It is a single html5 page with the listview page

```
                      id = '#employee_list_view_page'.
```

Or alternatively set it to stop (or timeout) after some seconds so the user dont think the app has crashed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you are saving to the new data to the local storage, but it seems like you are not reloading the list with the new data before the refresh, thats probably why the page doesn't get updated. On top of refreshing the listview you also need to manually call the function you would normally use to load data into the listview. Make sure you call this function before calling refresh. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks can you give me a clue on how to reload list view with the new data. In the form where I initially added the employee, I have this function employees.push(newEmployee); and addEmployee(newEmployee);

Comment: Thanks @ Lakmal I figured it out. as you said I was not reloading the list with the new data, I was missing out showEmployees(); function which now works